# Why isn't git letting me push my changes?

Tags: git, github

I'm using Git on Mac High Sierra.  I noticed I have a directory that has some changes ...

```
localhost:currency_calculator davea$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   currency-calculator (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So I tried to commit those changes using the below commands

```
localhost:currency_calculator davea$ git add .
localhost:currency_calculator davea$ git commit -m 'Added directory.'
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   currency-calculator (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit
```

but for some reason the above isn't working and I'm unable to push my changes to my master remote ...

```
localhost:currency_calculator davea$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

You have a *submodule:*

```
    modified:   currency-calculator (modified content, untracked content)
```

The annotations "modified content" and "untracked content" are the result of your Git asking the submodule Git for *its* `git status`, then summarizing what it said (that there are uncommitted files and untracked files) into a single line.

You must:

1. Commit the updated files into the submodule.  That is, enter the submodule (`cd currency-calculator`) and do all the usual things that one does in a Git repository to add and commit files.

   If the untracked files need to be committed, be sure to add them.  Note that the submodule repository is likely on a "detached HEAD", so before committing there, you'll probably want to re-attach its HEAD to some branch name, perhaps *creating* a branch if necessary.
2. Deliver any such commits to the server that serves that Git repository as the submodule (so that other people can get them).

   This is why you wanted to put the submodule on a branch in step 1: it's easier to push a branch than to do the push from a detached HEAD.  (It *is* possible to use a detached HEAD here, but I am not going to go into details.)

   Step 2 can be deferred a bit; see below.
3. Now that the desired commit exists in the submodule locally, update the hash ID in the *gitlink* in your index, then commit the result.

   In this case you would do this with:

   ```
   git add currency-calculator
   git commit
   ```

   in the appropriate part of the superproject repository.
4. Use `git push` in the superproject to deliver to the superproject's `origin` Git the new commit that uses the hash ID from the local submodule.

   Once you have done this, anyone who clones the superproject repository and then runs `git submodule update --init` will need to be able to access the submodule commit hash ID that you saved in the commit you made in step 3.  For them to do that, this commit hash ID will need to be in the repository to which you ran `git push` in step 2.  So *this* is when step 2 needs to be complete, at the moment someone *else* uses the superproject commit you made in step 3.

Note that there are a minimum of *four* Git repositories involved in this dance:

- your superproject;
- your superproject's `origin` Git;
- your submodule;
- your submodule's `origin` Git.

Each Git repository acquires a new commit either through `git commit` or through `git push`, so there are a total of four such commands to run: two `git commit`s and two `git push`es.

Comment: All of that aside, should we perhaps worry that the OP has a submodule named the same as his outer repo? Couldve been a mistake.